# PyTorch training loop within a sklearn pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pytorch, pipeline

What I am playing around with right now is to work with PyTorch within a pipeline, where all of the preprocessing will be handled.

I am able to make it work. However, the results I am getting are a bit off. The loss function seems to be not decreasing and gets stuck (presumably in local optima?) as the training loop progresses.

I follow the standard PyTorch training loop and wrap it inside the fit method as this is what sklearn wants:

```py
import torch
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin

import torch.nn.functional as F

from IPython.core.debugger import set_trace

# +
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

from tqdm import tqdm
import random
# -

df = sns.load_dataset("tips")
df.head()


# +
class LinearRegressionModel(torch.nn.Module, BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
 
    def __init__(self, loss_func = torch.nn.MSELoss()):
        super(LinearRegressionModel, self).__init__()
        self.linear = torch.nn.Linear(3, 1)  # One in and one out
        self.loss_func = loss_func
        self.optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(self.parameters(), lr = 0.01)
 
    def forward(self, x):
        y_pred = F.relu(self.linear(x))
        return y_pred    
    
    def fit(self, X, y):
        
#         set_trace()        

        X = torch.from_numpy(X.astype(np.float32))
        y = torch.from_numpy(y.values.astype(np.float32))
                
        for epoch in tqdm(range(0, 12)):
             
            pred_y = self.forward(X)

            # Compute and print loss
            loss = self.loss_func(pred_y, X)

            # Zero gradients, perform a backward pass,
            # and update the weights.
            self.optimizer.zero_grad()
            loss.backward()
            self.optimizer.step()
            print('epoch {}, loss {}'.format(epoch, loss.item()))            


# +
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

from sklego.preprocessing import PatsyTransformer
# -

my_model = LinearRegressionModel()

pipe = Pipeline([
    ("patsy", PatsyTransformer("tip + size")),
    ("model", my_model)
])

pipe.fit(df, df['total_bill'])
```

It is not only due to the model being to simple. If I use sklearn linear regression estimated via stochastic gradient descent (SGDRegressor) the results seem nice. Therefore, I am concluding that problem is within my PyTorch class

```py
# +
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

pipe2 = Pipeline([
    ("patsy", PatsyTransformer("tip + C(size) + C(time)")),
    ("model", LinearRegression())
])

pipe2.fit(df, df['total_bill'])
# -

mean_squared_error(df['total_bill'], pipe2.predict(df))
```

Comment: Could it be that the loss function is not improving simply because your model is too simple to learn the task better than it already did in the first step? Also, what do you mean by "the function gets stuck"?

Comment: Meaning that loss function get stuck in global optima (seems like that). but frankly I do not know if the problem is in code or in math :D.

Comment: One thing I notice - but no idea if relevant to your problem or not - is that the `MSELoss`' parameter `size_average` is [deprecated](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.MSELoss.html) ... and I'm not sure why you don't want to average them anyway?

Comment: Found the problem myself. in the class when calculation the loss function ```loss = self.loss_func(pred_y, X)```, we need to provide real values and not the design matrix. Should be ```loss = self.loss_func(pred_y, y)```

Comment: Oh, good catch! I'd write that as a self-answer if I were you - then you can accept it in a while, so the question is marked as completed. (I think it is worth keeping the question itself around - if only because it is a clear example on how to combine pytorch with an sklearn pipeline)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in this implementation is in the `fit` method.

We are comparing prediction and design matrix

```py
# Compute and print loss
loss = self.loss_func(pred_y, X)
```

Should be prediction and real value y:

```py
loss = self.loss_func(pred_y, y)
```